# Why ubuntu server does not mount fstab samba share on boot?

Tags: server, mount, samba, fstab

Ciao,

I've a Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 LTS.

I need to mount a samba share at boot time, and I've followed instructions on this site at sections *Mount password protected network folders*: [MountWindowsSharesPermanently](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently)

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
nano ~/.smbcredentials # there i've added my credentials
chmod 600 ~/.smbcredentials
sudo nano /etc/fstab
sudo mkdir /media/windowsshare
```

And I've added this line of code:

```
//{samba-share-ipaddress}/sharename /media/windowsshare cifs credentials=/home/{my-ubuntu-username}/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

When I execute the command *sudo mount -a*, the share is mounted correctly, but if I reboot, the folder is not mounted.

I've tried to add *_netdev* but without success:

```
//samba-share-ipaddress/sharename /media/windowsshare cifs credentials=/home/{my-ubuntu-username}/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,_netdev 0 0
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Did you edit `fstab`, or just ran `sudo nano /etc/fstab`?

Comment: Hi Pilot6, I've edites the fstab file with the configuration, when I execute sudo mount -a It works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it have to be mounted under /media?
Can it be mounted under /mnt instead?

The problem is most likely that the network stack on your Linux machine is not fully operational when the line in fstab is executed so at that point there is nothing to mount.

The current way around this is to add 2 more options to your fstab line:

```
noauto,x-systemd.automount
```

So your line becomes:

```
//{samba-share-ipaddress}/sharename /media/windowsshare cifs credentials=/home/{my-ubuntu-username}/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,noauto,x-systemd.automount 0 0
```

The only problem is since the mount point is under /media another process ( udisks2 ) tends to interfere with this process and it tries to mount it too early.

You can try it as is with the two additional parameters and if it doesn't work change the mount point to /mnt/windowsshare.